# Landau asymptotics for a product

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Suppose

- $f(v)=-dF(u)/du$
- $f(1)=f(-1)=0$
- $F(-1)=F(1)$
- $g(v):=2(F(v)-F(-1))=-2\int_{-1}^v f(u)\, du$,
- $\mu^2:=-f'(-1)=-f'(1)$

In particular, $g'(v)=-2f(v)$ and $g(1)=0$.

> > Now, it is claimed that by the definition of $g$ it is "quite standard" to get the estimate
> >     $$
> > f(v)g^{-1/2}(v)=\mu(1+O(1-v)),
> > $$

And, to be honest, I have literally no idea how to see this!

Comment: That's not true as is, the leading order estimate of $g^{-1/2}$ will have a $\mu^{-1/2}$ in it that will spoil that result. Did you maybe want the expansion of $g$ to not involve $\mu$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention extra information which I now added.

Comment: Still exactly the same issue as before.

Comment: You are right, I now added the whole context. Sorry for the chaos.

Comment: It seems to be assuming $f'(1)$ and hence $g''(1)$ are nonzero, while $g'(1)=0$. Thus g scales like $(1-v)^2$. Multiply and divide by $(1+v)^{-1}$ to get to $(1-v)^{-1} f (g (1-v)^{-2})^{-1/2}$ and then estimate g.

Comment: @Ian What I see is that $f(v)=f(1)+f'(1)(v-1)+O((v-1)^2)$ that is $f(v)=O(v-1)$. Moreoever, as you say, $g(v)=g(1)+g'(1)(v-1)+\frac{1}{2}g''(1)(v-1)^2+O((v-1)^3)=-f'(1)(v-1)^2+O((v-1)^3)$. Hence $g(v)=O((v-1)^2)$. Now I do not understand what you mean with $multiply and divide by...".

Comment: The point is to dodge this worry that you have about $g^{-1/2}$ near a point where $g=0$. It isn't essential, you can just expand for $v \neq 1$ and simplify and the singularity will still be removed.

Comment: Do they mean it that simple that $f(v)\approx f'(1)(v-1)=\mu^2(1-v)$ and $g(v)\approx \mu^2(1-v)^2$? But why is then $f(v)g(v)^{-1/2}=\mu(1+O(1-v))$? If I simply put this in, I get $f(v)g^{-1/2}(v)=\mu^2(1-v)\cdot(\mu^2(1-v)^2)^{-1/2}=\mu$.

Comment: The leading order term is just $\mu$, but there are corrections caused by deviation between $f$ and $g$ and their respective leading order approximations (which in the case of $g$ is not *directly* related to derivatives of $g$ since everything has to pass through that $-1/2$ power).